# identityReference.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString() not providing complete domain name

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I want to fetch all the groups an user is assigned to. I have used the code block mentioned below:

```
WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(userName);

IdentityReferenceCollection irc = windowsIdentity.Groups;

Console.WriteLine("The groups identified are : ");
foreach (IdentityReference identityReference in irc)
    Console.WriteLine(identityReference.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString());
```

One of the group detail for the user is:

- domainname for the group is example.com
- group name is Group1

Expected output is: `example.com\Group1`

Output I got is: `example\Group1`

Can anyone suggest how to get expected output.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Your domain has two names:

- DNS name, which can be looked up in DNS, like `example.com`
- NetBIOS name, which is a short name for the domain, used for convenience, like `EXAMPLE`

The NetBIOS name is usually similar to the DNS name, but without dots. However it doesn't have to be similar. You could have a domain DNS of `example.com`, but a NetBIOS name of `MYDOMAIN`.

When objects are shown the `domain\username` format, the NetBIOS name is always used. That's why you are seeing `EXAMPLE\Group1`. So that's entirely normal and expected.

Is there any reason you *must* have it in the format of `DNS name\username`? I don't know of any case where that is required.

As a side note, I wrote an article about getting all of a user's groups, which you may or may not find helpful: [Finding all of a user’s groups](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/08/finding-all-of-a-users-groups.html)

*Update:* If you really need the `DNS name\username` format, you can try this (this isn't tested, but it should be close). This will find the group in AD using the SID, then pull the domain's DNS name out of the `canonicalName` attribute.

```
foreach (SecurityIdentifier groupSid in irc) {
    using (var group = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<SID=" + groupSid.Value + ">")) {
        group.RefreshCache(new [] { "canonicalName", "sAMAccountName" });
        var canonicalName = group.Properties["canonicalName"].Value.ToString();
        var domainDns = canonicalName.Substring(0, canonicalName.IndexOf("/"));
        Console.WriteLine(domainDns + "\\" + group.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Gabriel.
Actually i need to compare it against a set of groups, and the group names in that set are in the format of example.com\Group1

Comment: Why are they in that format? Where did that come from? That format doesn't come from anywhere in AD. It would have had to be manually constructed like that.

Comment: If you really do need that format, I added some code to my answer that should help.